# Crash with objc_msgSend() selector name: countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:

Tags: cocoa, crash, nstableview, nsview, nswindow

My cocoa app occasionally crashes with the above specific information. I'm sure that it's due to NSTableView display in my app but I can't figure out what's wrong. The crash report is as below. Can anyone tell what's going on?

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8847a0dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ae1a44a -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 6008
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8add12be -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1876
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8add0b19 -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 236
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8add0782 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 936
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b506191 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1540 + 46
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8dd32127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8dd32080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8dd24188 __CFRunLoopRun + 872
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8dd23bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff950db56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff950db2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff950db12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8adcd9bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8adccf68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8adc2bf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ad3f354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8980e5c9 start + 1
```

Comment: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Comment: Thanks but I think the link does not really address what I'm looking into. Can you point me to read for something which leads to solving my issue?